# MySQL Find a line of text in a LONGTEXT column

Tags: mysql

How can you return the line of a paragraph from a LONGTEXT column, if you know what the line of text starts with?

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING('\nA line of text starts here', `paragraphs`)
FROM books
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using "LIKE". % indicates that more characters can follow.

```
SELECT paragraphs FROM books WHERE paragraphs LIKE '\nA line of text starts here%'
```